# null pointer exception can't assign value in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I know there are billions of the same question but I actually can't handle this one. Here's my code that causes the the problem:

```
public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CategoryAdapter.CategoryAdapterClickHandler {
    @Override
    public void onClick(String name) {

    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> items;

    static String catName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        //get intent and extra text
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        catName = intent.getStringExtra("categoryName");
        Log.e("fwdf", catName);

        //execute categoryTask;
        new CategoryAsyncTask(){
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> categoryItems) {
                super.onPostExecute(categoryItems);
                items = categoryItems;
            }
        }.execute(catName);

        //initialize recyclerview and set it to its adapter
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        Log.e("fgjhkkl;",items.get(1));
        mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, this, items, false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

The error happened because items variable is null although the categoryItems isn't null and I assigned items to categryItems.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use the items before the AsyncTask is done.

To solve (for example), move

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager =
        new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, this, items, false);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

to the end of the `onPostExecute` function

Comment: nope, asynch mean asynchronous so response can take time so won't work all the time

Comment: there's errors cause i'll be using "this" in categoryAdapter constructor

Comment: change `this` to `CategoryActivity.this`